# $.ajaxSetup in js vanilla

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a jquery ajaxSetup which I want to convert in JS vanilla working cross browser.

So I need the same action (presetting  data for all future **jquery AJAX** calls) written in JS vanilla.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        "_token": ajax_token
    }
});
```

Which means I need this setup to be in JS vanilla, but I'll use jquery ajax after that (in rest of the code).

Have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery ajaxSetup with ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709415/jquery-ajaxsetup-with-es6)

Comment: I don't want for ES6 in particulary.

Comment: Not sure what you expect,  Jquery makes a wrapper around the call, there is no such wrapper with plain old calls. Only way to get that is code your own wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The `ajaxSetup` method in jQuery works because when the various ajax methods in jQuery run, they check the place where `ajaxSetup` stores its data to see if they need to act other differently to the default.

`ajaxSetup` is the entry point that the jQuery library uses to store data in that place. It is internal to jQuery and you can't access it other than through that entry point.